# Subquery working in MySQL workbench but not PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query in MySQL Workbench that works flawlessly when executed. When I run it in PHP on my website, the columns which are sub-queried show up blank.

```
<?php
 $sql_query = "SELECT PROJECTNOID, ProjectNumber, (SELECT StatusHold FROM 
tblProjectStatus WHERE ProjectStatus = PROJECTSTATUSID), EnteredDate FROM 
tblProjects ORDER BY PROJECTNOID";
```

I have removed the other four subqueries for simplicity.

```
 echo $sql_query;
 $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query) or die("database error:". 
 mysqli_error($conn));
 while($developer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
 ?>
 <tr id="<?php echo $developer ['PROJECTNOID']; ?>">
 <td><?php echo $developer ['PROJECTNOID']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['ProjectNumber']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['ProjectStatus']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['CustomerProjectLeadID']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['MGEProjectLeadID']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['ProjectStatusNumberID']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['ProjectTitle']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['SubmittedDate']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['StartDate']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['CompletionDate']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['Follow-Up']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['Comments']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['ProjectEnteredBy']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $developer ['EnteredDate']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Expected output:

[image]

Without The subqueries columns 3,4,5, and 6 would show up with numbers instead.

Comment: Any specific error seen while executing this query?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh No error shows up, just an undesired output.

Comment: May be database on server doesn't have the same data as on local system database.

Comment: What is the expected output of `(SELECT StatusHold FROM 
tblProjectStatus WHERE ProjectStatus = PROJECTSTATUSID)`. And if the query is working as you described in your post, what is output of `$sql_query`. Try to add more debugging information.

Comment: Make sure the subquery only returns one result; and it might help to qualify the field names with their tables.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh I have added dbname.tblBlah to all table names but the output is the same. I don't know if this answers what you just said though.

Comment: @JordanMack he was suggesting you were running the query on copies of the database on servers, and that there might be a difference in the data.

Comment: @BasvanDijk The expected output is shown in this image. This is the same query ran in MySQL workbench. Sorry for the hack job of covering up names. [subquery](https://imgur.com/a/lHjShLp)

Comment: @JordanMack What image are you talking about?

Comment: @BasvanDijk [IMAGE](https://imgur.com/a/lHjShLp)

Comment: It's usually better to use `JOIN` rather than correlated subqueries.

Comment: The query in your image is different from the one in the question, it has multiple subqueries.

Comment: @Barmar How would the JOIN statement look? Yes, I have removed them to make the question more simple to ask. The subquery in my question is the third column in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the aliases are missing, eg. try something like :

```
SELECT PROJECTNOID, ProjectNumber, (SELECT StatusHold FROM 
tblProjectStatus WHERE ProjectStatus = PROJECTSTATUSID) AS StatusHold, EnteredDate FROM 
tblProjects ORDER BY PROJECTNOID
```

On a second note, it's not very clear what are you trying to achieve but it's better to use joins than sub queries.

Comment: Nice! I switched AS StatusHold to AS ProjectStatus and it worked. Thank You!